# Why is my grid not aligning properly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel

I'm using Photoshop CS6 and for some reason the grid is not aligned 1 pixel by 1 pixel on my 20 pixel by 20 pixel image. I've tried everything and it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

here are my settings:

[image: empty canvas]

Guides,grids and slices

[image: preferences]:

views:

[image: views]

p.s: I'm new to photoshop

Comment: "Photoshop CS6 portable" is not an Adobe product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have the solution:

If you go to `view -> show` and *remove* the show `grid`, but choose the `pixel grid`, it should work (provided you have set the document to x number of pixels hight and width).

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but setting the grid for every 2 pixel then subdivide by 2 worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

there is a simple solution here with just the Grid

first zoom into your picture size, then choose the Preferences->Guides,Grid...

then at that point choose the Pixel size to whatever you want, and subdivions to 1 obviously , if it is set to alredy what you want just change it to somethng random and back to what you want to force Photoshop to recalculate and redrawn the pixel grid to your canvas size

here at this point Photoshop should make the correct calculations and drawn align the pixel grid to your canvas correctly and hence you should get proper pixel size to canvas size that align correctly

so if you change canvas size by zooming or otherwise, then just go back to the preference and again do this process to get correct pixel grid calculations and alignment