# Pixel grid and Grid don't align in Photoshop CC (PS CS6 provided as a reference)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel, cc-2014

This is how it should be (PS CS6)

[image: Pixel grid vs grid PS CS6]

This is how it is (PS CC)

[image: Pixel grid vs grid PS CC]

Seems to be some kind of issue with some kind of measurements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my grid not aligning properly?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/why-is-my-grid-not-aligning-properly)

Answer (score 1):

Of course they don't align: You will have to calculate how many subdivisions the Grid should have to match the Pixel Grid.

Comment: Matching Grid with Pixel Grid is not an issue here (both CS6 and CC examples above are 1:1), therefore question you suggested might have an answer I'm looking for is not relevant, but thanks for your try.

The solution was re-enabling grid (I've been doing that for the past two months occasionally but nothing would have happened - now it's magically gone, some kind of a visual bug it seems).

Answer (score 1):

Re-enabling grid - I've been doing that for the past two months occasionally but nothing would have happened but now it's magically gone, some kind of a visual bug it seems.