# Why is Photoshop's pixel grid smaller than my actual pixels?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grids, pixel, cc-2014

[image: photoshop pixel art issue]

I'm trying to set up Photoshop cc 2014 for pixel art graphics, but I have this weird issue where my pixels don't align to the grid. I can't work out if it's my pencil which is creating pixels too big, or the grid is somehow wrong. I've set the grid to 1:1 so I'm not sure how that could be any different.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I'm on a Mac if that makes any difference.

Comment: Whats the resolution of your file?

Comment: 72 pixels/inch, standard photoshop setup.

Comment: @that's the problem

Comment: How is that the problem? looking at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFZBUWHVSrM he sets it up the same way.

Comment: Standard photoshop setup

Comment: My updated my asnwer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my grid not aligning properly?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26610/why-is-my-grid-not-aligning-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the resolution of your file is so big for pixel art Photoshop is showing you the *other* Grid (not the pixel grid), You have to disable the Grid:

**View > Show > Make sure Grid is unchecked and Pixel Grid is Checked**

[image]

Also: Reduce the resolution of your file to something like 24x24 and select a square brush.

Comment: Are you talking about the resolution or the pixel width/height? the res is 72 px/inch and the width/height is 100x100, what difference would making it 24x24 make?

Comment: Where is "Pixel Grid" ? I can't find that.

Comment: The resolution of your file is irrelevant as long as you are viewing it at actual size (or larger)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your "Grid" to match the "Pixel Grid" just set it up like this:

Gridline Every: 2 Pixels

Subdivisions: 2

Comment: It doesn't make any sense but it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to <kbd>Edit → Preferences → Guides, Grids and Slices</kbd> and then change gridline to 1 pixel (from the drop down menu) and subdivisions to 1. Then your grid will align with your pencil and canvas

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like [@josh said](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46204/41874), thought the pixels where 2 pixels big now. I have changed it back to 1 pixel and this time it worked.

I still don't know how this worked but I'm happy with the result.

Answer (score -1):

This post is old but the solution is - switch everything to 2 - the pencil, as well as the grid divisions and subdivisions. Then switch back to 1 in everything. This happened in Photoshop CS5 for me in spite of everything being already set to one. So I switched everything to 2 then back to 1

Comment: Is that the same effect for the current CS? And what is the difference to the answer of Josh?

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is that you are zoomed out on the grid to far. Photoshop changes the grid size if the pixels are to small. Its not really a problem, just zoom in if you want to see the true grid size.

Comment: Wrong. That is the grid (which you can setup to whatever size you want) as stated in the accepted answer.